# Parameter of OneHotEncoder : Categories

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, parameters, one-hot-encoding, label-encoding

I have been coding on ML via Scikit-learn from few months.
but a update has came on scikit object of preprocessing which is OneHotEncoder.
here was a parameter categorical_features which is now changed to categories and now i am not understanding how to writes is values

**The code which I am writing is :**

`from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder , OneHotEncoder`

`le = LabelEncoder()`
`X[:,0] = le.fit_transform(X[:,0])`

`ohe = OneHotEncoder(categories = X[:,0].all())`
`X = ohe.fit_transform(X).toarray()`

**and is showing this error**

*runcell(0, 'C:/Mobile Videos/OPencv/opencv-master/samples/data/untitled2.py')*
*Traceback (most recent call last):*

*File "C:\Mobile Videos\OPencv\opencv-master\samples\data\untitled2.py", line 25, in* 
    *X = ohe.fit_transform(X).toarray()*

*File "C:\Users\Harshit\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing_encoders.py", line 372, in* *fit_transform*
    *return super().fit_transform(X, y)*

*File "C:\Users\Harshit\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 571, in fit_transform*
    *return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)*

*File "C:\Users\Harshit\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing_encoders.py", line 347, in fit*
    *self._fit(X, handle_unknown=self.handle_unknown)*

*File "C:\Users\Harshit\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing_encoders.py", line 77, in* *_fit*
    *if len(self.categories) != n_features:*

*TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()*

And if I am making the parameter auto then it is changing the whole data set into code like while changing the Label to code

Could you please help me out from this problem?????